# How to get unique array from sub-document filed of object array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say you have documents in your collection and each document has an array of objects and you want to get in your projection a distinct array of one of your fields in these objects, how do you do that?

for example, your collection includes 2 documents:

```
db.products.insertMany([
            {name:"A",subarray:[{id:1,value:1},{id:1,value:2},{id:2,value:3}]},
            {name:"B",subarray:[{id:1,value:1},{id:2,value:2},{id:3,value:3}]},
            {name:"C",subarray:[{id:2,value:1},{id:2,value:2},{id:3,value:3}]}])
```

and you want to get this (unique_id array of the id's of each document ):

```
{ "name" : "a", "unique_id" : [ 1, 2 ] }
{ "name" : "b", "unique_id" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
{ "name" : "b", "unique_id" : [ 2, 3 ] }
```

how do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) and [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/index.html) like this:

```
db.products.aggregate([{
    $project:{
        _id:0,
        name:1,
        unique_id:{
            $reduce:{
                input: "$subarray.id",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                  $setUnion: ["$$value", ["$$this"]]
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}])
```